# Why does a service need a process affiliated with it?

Tags: windows, winapi, service, process

In my research of "what is a process" every page keeps saying that it's exactly like a process but no GUI. So why does it need/have a PID? On top of that, I've seen 2 services with the same PID.

What's the real relationship between services and processes?

Comment: [This topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and its children explain it all very clearly.

Answer (score 0):

No two processes can have the same PID. Difference between service & process is that the service doesn't have user associated with it so it starts before any user login to the system where as process usually runs with a user login token.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 2 services with the same PID. And thanks for your answer. I haven't found that said yet. Do you happen to have a source?

Comment: Services is also  processes running in session 0 with GUI & no user token associated with it. There are services in windows which are implemented as dlls & they need to run from a service process. Single service process may load multiple dll services in that case you will see main process ID associated with the dll services.

Comment: Multiple services can run in a single process if they are created with the `SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS` flag enabled.  That flag does not require DLLs be used.  All that is required is the EXE's `ServiceMain()` recognize requests for multiple service names running at the same time. This allows related services to share memory and code with each other.